# JavaFX 8: change colour of a specific circle with his own id

Tags: javafx, colors, geometry

I ve created this program that when you click on "create" button other two ButtonBar (called newNode) are created.. inside this Button bar there are a button and a circle. When all is created I would like to change the colour of these two circle when i click another Button. I ve coded something but I can just change the colour of the LAST circle.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

@FXML
private Button btnHaveFun;
@FXML
private ButtonBar ReadSMSBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar GalleryBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar FileExplorerBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar SpyCamBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar TakeAPictureBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar TakeAScreenshotBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar RecordAVideoBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar SpyWhatsappBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar KeyLoggerBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar ScreenStreamBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar SpyMicrophoneBar;
@FXML
private ButtonBar slaveBar;
@FXML
private VBox slaveVbox;
@FXML
private Circle statusSlave;

private ButtonBar newNode = new ButtonBar();
private Circle c= new Circle();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}    
public void creat(String s){
    newNode = new ButtonBar();
    c= new Circle();
    c.setRadius(11);
    c.setStrokeWidth(1);
    c.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("#ffffff"));
    c.setFill(Paint.valueOf("#15ff00"));
    c.setId(s);
    newNode.getButtons().addAll(new Button("Mavero"),c);
    slaveVbox.getChildren().addAll(newNode) ;
}

@FXML
public void newComp(){      
    creat("id1");
    creat("id2");
}

@FXML
public void change(){
 c.setFill(Color.BLACK);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of all circles at once to the same color? Or to change the specific circle's to specific color?

Comment: I would like to change color of a specific one.. (in this case the first circle created.. the one that has "id1" as ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Node.lookup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) to get the `Circle`s using a css selector (or [`Node.lookupAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-) for multiple nodes):

```
void change(String oldId, String newId) {
    change(oldId, Color.RED);
    change(newId, Color.GREEN);
}

void change(String id, Color color){
    Circle circle = (Circle) slaveVbox.lookup('#'+id);
    circle.setFill(color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple:

Just add All Circles in a List ->

```
    List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();

public void creat(String s) {
    newNode = new ButtonBar();
    Circle c = new Circle();
    c.setRadius(11);
    c.setStrokeWidth(1);
    c.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("#ffffff"));
    c.setFill(Paint.valueOf("#15ff00"));
    c.setId(s);
    circles.add(c);
    newNode.getButtons().addAll(new Button("Mavero"), c);
    slaveVbox.getChildren().addAll(newNode);
}

@FXML
public void newComp() {
    creat("id1");
    creat("id2");
}

@FXML
public void change() {
    for (Circle c : circles) {
        c.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would change the colour of all circles.. but I would like to change the colour of the first circle created (the one that has "id1" as ID).. I could set an if statment in your for loop but is there something more direct than this?

Comment: And also the List can't be used as you did.. it gives error.

Comment: You can use as Fabian answered the lookup funktion but the list/loop method is faster.   What error gives it?